# Using 2.4" MCUFriend TFT LCD Display with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am hoping that someone is familiar with the 2.4" TFT LCD Display board from MCUFriend. I am having troubling using this board with my Arduino Uno and I was hoping someone could help.

The problem that I am having is that there are all of these colored lines being drawn on the screen after a reset and initialization. Right now all i am trying to do is fill the screen and draw a box. here is my code:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <TouchScreen.h>
#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h>

//SPI Communication
#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_CD A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0 
#define LCD_RESET A4 

//Color Definitons
#define BLACK   0x0000
#define WHITE   0xFFFF

#define BOXSIZE  40

Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  tft.reset();  
  tft.begin();

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.drawRect(100, 100, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE, WHITE);
}

void loop() {

}
```

This is what my Screen is doing:

[image]

As you can see, the background is black, and a box is being drawn behind these colored bars.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Im new to Arduino myself but i do have the same screen which works perfect,your problem is probably that the TFT shield is shorting off the top off the arduino usb put something non conductive there and reset. if your still having trouble, try removing the shield and watch each pin as you insert it to make sure they are all inserted in the correct pins, LCD_02 should be in Dig pin 2.
here is the code i used for testing, it uses the same library, Hope that helps you.

```
        #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
    #include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h> // Hardware-specific library

    // The control pins for the LCD can be assigned to any digital or
    // analog pins...but we'll use the analog pins as this allows us to
    // double up the pins with the touch screen (see the TFT paint example).
    #define LCD_CS A3 // Chip Select goes to Analog 3
    #define LCD_CD A2 // Command/Data goes to Analog 2
    #define LCD_WR A1 // LCD Write goes to Analog 1
    #define LCD_RD A0 // LCD Read goes to Analog 0

    #define LCD_RESET A4 // Can alternately just connect to Arduino's reset pin

    // When using the BREAKOUT BOARD only, use these 8 data lines to the LCD:
    // For the Arduino Uno, Duemilanove, Diecimila, etc.:
    //   D0 connects to digital pin 8  (Notice these are
    //   D1 connects to digital pin 9   NOT in order!)
    //   D2 connects to digital pin 2
    //   D3 connects to digital pin 3
    //   D4 connects to digital pin 4
    //   D5 connects to digital pin 5
    //   D6 connects to digital pin 6
    //   D7 connects to digital pin 7
    // For the Arduino Mega, use digital pins 22 through 29
    // (on the 2-row header at the end of the board).

    // Assign human-readable names to some common 16-bit color values:
    #define BLACK   0x0000
    #define BLUE    0x001F
    #define RED     0xF800
    #define GREEN   0x07E0
    #define CYAN    0x07FF
    #define MAGENTA 0xF81F
    #define YELLOW  0xFFE0
    #define WHITE   0xFFFF

    Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("TFT LCD test"));

#ifdef USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT
  Serial.println(F("Using Adafruit 2.8\" TFT Arduino Shield Pinout"));
#else
  Serial.println(F("Using Adafruit 2.8\" TFT Breakout Board Pinout"));
#endif

  Serial.print("TFT size is "); Serial.print(tft.width()); Serial.print("x"); Serial.println(tft.height());

  tft.reset();

  uint16_t identifier = tft.readID();

  if(identifier == 0x9325) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9325 LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x9327) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9327 LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x9328) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9328 LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x7575) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8347G LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x9341) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9341 LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x8357) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8357D LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x0154) {
    Serial.println(F("Found S6D0154 LCD driver"));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("Unknown LCD driver chip: "));
    Serial.println(identifier, HEX);
    Serial.println(F("If using the Adafruit 2.8\" TFT Arduino shield, the line:"));
    Serial.println(F("  #define USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT"));
    Serial.println(F("should appear in the library header (Adafruit_TFT.h)."));
    Serial.println(F("If using the breakout board, it should NOT be #defined!"));
    Serial.println(F("Also if using the breakout, double-check that all wiring"));
    Serial.println(F("matches the tutorial."));
    return;
  }

  tft.begin(identifier);

  Serial.println(F("Benchmark                Time (microseconds)"));

  Serial.print(F("Screen fill              "));
  Serial.println(testFillScreen());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Text                     "));
  Serial.println(testText());
  delay(3000);

  Serial.print(F("Lines                    "));
  Serial.println(testLines(CYAN));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Horiz/Vert Lines         "));
  Serial.println(testFastLines(RED, BLUE));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rectangles (outline)     "));
  Serial.println(testRects(GREEN));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rectangles (filled)      "));
  Serial.println(testFilledRects(YELLOW, MAGENTA));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Circles (filled)         "));
  Serial.println(testFilledCircles(10, MAGENTA));

  Serial.print(F("Circles (outline)        "));
  Serial.println(testCircles(10, WHITE));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Triangles (outline)      "));
  Serial.println(testTriangles());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Triangles (filled)       "));
  Serial.println(testFilledTriangles());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rounded rects (outline)  "));
  Serial.println(testRoundRects());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rounded rects (filled)   "));
  Serial.println(testFilledRoundRects());
  delay(500);

  Serial.println(F("Done!"));
}

void loop(void) {
  for(uint8_t rotation=0; rotation<4; rotation++) {
    tft.setRotation(rotation);
    testText();
    delay(2000);
  }
}

unsigned long testFillScreen() {
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.fillScreen(RED);
  tft.fillScreen(GREEN);
  tft.fillScreen(BLUE);
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testText() {
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(YELLOW); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println(1234.56);
  tft.setTextColor(RED);    tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println(0xDEADBEEF, HEX);
  tft.println();
  tft.setTextColor(GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(5);
  tft.println("Groop");
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("I implore thee,");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("my foonting turlingdromes.");
  tft.println("And hooptiously drangle me");
  tft.println("with crinkly bindlewurdles,");
  tft.println("Or I will rend thee");
  tft.println("in the gobberwarts");
  tft.println("with my blurglecruncheon,");
  tft.println("see if I don't!");
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testLines(uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start, t;
  int           x1, y1, x2, y2,
                w = tft.width(),
                h = tft.height();

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1 = y1 = 0;
  y2    = h - 1;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = w - 1;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t     = micros() - start; // fillScreen doesn't count against timing

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1    = w - 1;
  y1    = 0;
  y2    = h - 1;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = 0;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t    += micros() - start;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1    = 0;
  y1    = h - 1;
  y2    = 0;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = w - 1;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t    += micros() - start;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1    = w - 1;
  y1    = h - 1;
  y2    = 0;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = 0;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFastLines(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           x, y, w = tft.width(), h = tft.height();

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(y=0; y<h; y+=5) tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, w, color1);
  for(x=0; x<w; x+=5) tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, h, color2);

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testRects(uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           n, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2,
                cy = tft.height() / 2;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  n     = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  start = micros();
  for(i=2; i<n; i+=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.drawRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color);
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledRects(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  unsigned long start, t = 0;
  int           n, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  n = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  for(i=n; i>0; i-=6) {
    i2    = i / 2;
    start = micros();
    tft.fillRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color1);
    t    += micros() - start;
    // Outlines are not included in timing results
    tft.drawRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color2);
  }

  return t;
}

unsigned long testFilledCircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int x, y, w = tft.width(), h = tft.height(), r2 = radius * 2;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(x=radius; x<w; x+=r2) {
    for(y=radius; y<h; y+=r2) {
      tft.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testCircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           x, y, r2 = radius * 2,
                w = tft.width()  + radius,
                h = tft.height() + radius;

  // Screen is not cleared for this one -- this is
  // intentional and does not affect the reported time.
  start = micros();
  for(x=0; x<w; x+=r2) {
    for(y=0; y<h; y+=r2) {
      tft.drawCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testTriangles() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           n, i, cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                      cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  n     = min(cx, cy);
  start = micros();
  for(i=0; i<n; i+=5) {
    tft.drawTriangle(
      cx    , cy - i, // peak
      cx - i, cy + i, // bottom left
      cx + i, cy + i, // bottom right
      tft.color565(0, 0, i));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledTriangles() {
  unsigned long start, t = 0;
  int           i, cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                   cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(i=min(cx,cy); i>10; i-=5) {
    start = micros();
    tft.fillTriangle(cx, cy - i, cx - i, cy + i, cx + i, cy + i,
      tft.color565(0, i, i));
    t += micros() - start;
    tft.drawTriangle(cx, cy - i, cx - i, cy + i, cx + i, cy + i,
      tft.color565(i, i, 0));
  }

  return t;
}

unsigned long testRoundRects() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           w, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  w     = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  start = micros();
  for(i=0; i<w; i+=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.drawRoundRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, i/8, tft.color565(i, 0, 0));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledRoundRects() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(i=min(tft.width(), tft.height()); i>20; i-=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.fillRoundRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, i/8, tft.color565(0, i, 0));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that sample, Tom :)
The defaults weren't giving me any results and I was getting annoyed. I noticed on my LCD that there are two pins which look to have a tiny bridge of solder connecting them. At first I thought that might be the cause of the trouble I was having, but seeing the screen working is a relief. When my solder wick comes in I'll clean up the board.
OP may want to check for bad solder joints too.

Answer (score 1):

in line:

uint16_t identifier = tft.readID();

you can fix your LCD driver like this:

uint16_t identifier = 0x7575; //Change according your LDC DRIVER ID, look in serial (Serial.println(identifier, HEX));